# Passing data in PreviewProvider SwiftUI, ObservableObject class, ObservedObject

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, observableobject, observedobject

I guys, I have a class with some properties (class ReservationInfo). In my first screen (ReservationFormView) I create an instance of the class(myReservationInfo).
I pass the data with a NavigationLink to the second view (ReservationRecapView). It works all right, but I have a problem with the SwiftUI preview. How can I pass some example data to the preview provider?

```
class ReservationInfo: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var customerName: String = ""
    @Published var surname : String = ""
    @Published var nPeople : Int = 1
    @Published var date = Date()
    
    
}
```

```
struct ReservationFormView: View {
    
    @StateObject var myReservationInfo = ReservationInfo()
    @State private var showSecondView = false
    
    init() {
        UIStepper.appearance().setDecrementImage(UIImage(systemName: "minus"), for: .normal)
        UIStepper.appearance().setIncrementImage(UIImage(systemName: "plus"), for: .normal)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                
                Text("Little lemon")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10.0)
                
                Label("Reservation Form", systemImage: "fork.knife")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .padding(.bottom, 30)
                
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30.0){
                    
                    TextField("Type your name", text: $myReservationInfo.customerName, onEditingChanged: {print($0)})
                        .onChange(of: myReservationInfo.customerName, perform: { newValue in print(newValue)})
                        .onSubmit {
                            print("submitted")
                        }
                    
                        .underlineTextField()
                    
                    TextField("Type your surname", text: $myReservationInfo.surname)
                        .underlineTextField()
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 30.0){
                        Label("\(myReservationInfo.nPeople)", systemImage: "person.fill")
                            .font(.title2)
                        Stepper("N di persone", value: $myReservationInfo.nPeople , in: 1...20)
                            .labelsHidden()
                            .accentColor(.blue)
                    }
                    .padding(.top)
                    
                    DatePicker(
                        "Select date",
                        selection: $myReservationInfo.date,
                        in: Date.now...,
                        displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute]
                    )
                    .onChange(of: myReservationInfo.date, perform: {date in print(date)})
                    .padding(.bottom, 20.0)
                }
                NavigationLink{
                    ReservationRecapView(myReservationInfo: myReservationInfo)
                } label: {
                Text("Avanti")
                    .padding(.horizontal, 70.0)
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 10)
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                
            }
            
            .padding(.horizontal, 30.0)
            .padding(.bottom, 100.0)
            .environmentObject(myReservationInfo)
        }
        
    }
        
    
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ReservationFormView()
        }
    }
}

extension Color {
    static let darkPink = Color(red: 208 / 255, green: 45 / 255, blue: 208 / 255)
}

extension View {
    func underlineTextField() -> some View {
        self
            .autocorrectionDisabled(true)
            .overlay(Rectangle().frame(height: 2).padding(.top, 40))
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
}
```

```
struct ReservationRecapView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var myReservationInfo : ReservationInfo
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10.0){
            Text(myReservationInfo.customerName)
            Text(myReservationInfo.surname)
            Text("Number of people \(myReservationInfo.nPeople)")
            Text(myReservationInfo.date, style: .date)
            Text(myReservationInfo.date, style: .time)
        }.font(.title2)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReservationRecapView(myReservationInfo: ReservationInfo())
    }
}
```

I don't know how to pass date in the PreviewProvider

Comment: Please consider making a minimal example... including irrelevant code, such as fonts, colors, etc, can make your code harder to understand and answer. You also don't need `ReservationFormView` in this question, since it isn't used outside of its declaration :)

Comment: In `ReservationFormView`, your preview struct is inside of your view... you should take it out and make it a separate struct. You also shouldn't have 2 different `ContentView_Previews` preview objects.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I need to pass data in the ReservationRecapView where I have the observable object. If I initialise the variable in the class with some data, the preview provider works fine with the data. But on this way when I open the app I have the text field precompiled.